# End of the (next) month from a random date

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

I have a question what is the fastest way to get **end of the month** from a day. I have a really large table and I want my code to be fast. My current code looks as follows:

```
library(lubridate)

end_of_month <- function(date){
 day(date) <- days_in_month(date)
 date
}
```

I have another question. Is it a fast way to get a last day of the next month from a random date?

```
"2019-05-15" %>% as.Date() %m+% months(1) %>% end_of_month  # 2019-06-30
```

Can I do this in one step or do I need an extra function to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Thanks to @Edward for pointing out the issue in the original answer.

You can use `ceiling_date` after adding 1 month to the original date

```
ceiling_date(as.Date('2019-05-15') + months(1), unit = "month") - 1
#[1] "2019-06-30"

ceiling_date(as.Date('2019-04-15') + months(1), unit = "month") - 1
#[1] "2019-05-31"
```

---

**Old Answer**

We can use `ceiling_date` with `unit` as `'2 months'`

```
library(lubridate)
'2019-05-15' %>% as.Date() %>% ceiling_date(unit = '2 months') - 1
#[1] "2019-06-30"
```

Comment: @Edward I haven't tested but it should. Also should consider leap years.

Comment: OK. It's just that your code (as well as the OP's) returns 1 month ahead for even months, but 2 months ahead for odd ones. So I'm scratching my head.

Comment: @Edward You are right. The original answer wasn't working as expected. I have updated the answer. Thank you for pointing that out.